# windows service with c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

i made a windows service but it didn't add rows to database correctly and the error is 
"it ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "AzkarDB" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'WORKGROUP\DESKTOP-NCJ94PQ$'"

can anyone help me to fix it ?
i debug the code in windows application and it added a row to database

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
    }
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        sendMessages();
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
        timer.Interval = 5000;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    public void sendMessages()
    {
            AzkarDBEntities ctx = new AzkarDBEntities();
            ctx.Messages.Add(new Message { content = "it works", status = 
  "new", date = "new", time = "new" });
            ctx.SaveChanges();

        }
    }
```

Comment: What does "it didn't work correctly" mean?  Lot's of things can go wrong when you are writing and installing a service.  Speaking of which, what does your installer code look like?

Comment: didn't add row to the database and didn't want to install without try and catch at send message function @Flydog57

Comment: How does this even compile? You have an extra closing brace in the event handler for the timer (before the try), making it an empty method.

Comment: So, did it compile (@JamieMeyer's comment is valid)?  Did the service start up?  If it started, make your interval time quite a bit longer, and quickly attach a debugger to the process (if you don't run the service as "you", then you'll need to run VS as admin).  and put a break point on `OnElapsedTime`.  Then you can debug it like any other app (more or less).

Comment: I'd recommend testing your code in a simple console application, where you can step through it and troubleshoot it. Once you have it working, you can change it into a service.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have no rights to access the database with the default service user. You can start the service with your own user account. If you use try catch then you should log the error to a file. Otherwise remove the try catch and look in the event viewer to get information about the error.